# Anchor tags causing route problems with UI Bootstrap for Angular

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been experimenting with various UI libraries for AngularJS and have settled on [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). However, I am having problems with the dropdown component.

If I use anchor tags on the 'li' elements then the links render nicely in the dropdown but this interferes with the routing system. If I remove the 'a' tags then the dropdowns do not render correctly.

Is there any way of having the items render correctly without using anchor tags?

Thanks, M

Comment: try adding `target="_self"` to your anchor tags. It skips angular router

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of interference with the routing system you're experiencing, but a sure fire way to screw up routing seems to be to use href="#" links in anchor tags. If that happens to be the case for you, using href="#/" will prevent the issue and retain the functionality.